# Code fails at case '0' - I don't understand why

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement

Here is a minimal form of the code emphasizing the issue I have.
Code fails at "exit"(case '0') - program simply crashes. I suspect it is related to the while loop. 
The issue occurs no matter what character i choose for the exit case (instead of '0').

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int run=1;
    char menu_option; 

    while (run==1) 
    {
        printf("Choose case:\n");
        scanf ("%s", &menu_option);
        switch (menu_option) {
        case '1':
        printf("1");
        break;

        case '2':
        printf("2");
        break;

        case '0':
        run=0;
        break;

        default:
        printf("Wrong input, try again\n");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf ("%s", &menu_option);` is either a type error or a semantic error, but you really need to post a [mcve].

Comment: I think it is something trivial that i'm missing here. I want the program to finish when user inputs '0'. So in case '0' i set "run" to be 0. for some reason the software crashes when choosing this case (even if i change the case from '0' to any other character)

Comment: Was that supposed to be a reply to my comment?

Comment: Since you can't use a string for a switch case it would seem that `scanf ("%s", &menu_option);` should be `scanf (" %c", &menu_option);` and note the added space. Since the use of `%s` will write 2 bytes to memory, at the least, when `menu_option` is perhaps `char` and so has only one byte, leaves the resulting behaviour not worth examining.

Comment: On the other hand, if `menu_option` really is a string  the switch test should be `switch(menu_option[0)` and I think the compiler warnings should have something to say either way.

Comment: As @melpomene asked I've updated the post. Hopefully, the issue will be clearer.

Comment: If you ask others to read your code; it is polite (and to your benefit) to make it readable and use conventional indentation.  Fixed it.

Comment: Fails how?  What happens?  Fails at run-time? Fails to compile?  Error message?

Comment: Sorry about that. It is my first post. The code was compilable i must have done something wrong while copy/past it. The thing is that the software crashes when the "exit" case is chosen.

Comment: You already have your answer.  melpomene pointed out your error and @chux suggested two ways to fix. Your posted code does not address the problem.

Comment: @EranAmsellem : It was my error - it was not an additional `}`, but an opening `{` hidden in the `switch`line.  Inconsistent brace and indent style is unhelpfully error prone.  I edited the comment before you responded.  Apologies.

Comment: @MFisherKDX :  I see no comment from chux - did you mean Weather Vane?

Comment: Yeah. I meant weathervane. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`menu_option` is not a string, so `%s` is the wrong format specifier.  You need `%c`, prefixed with a space to prevent whitespace (including newline) being interpreted as valid character input.

```
    scanf (" %c", &menu_option);
```

Comment: Thank you @Clifford it works!. Though, i still don't understand why the issue happened only for the "exit" case and not for the other cases ('1' & '2') which to me seems similar - what is the difference between the cases?

Comment: In my test it "worked" for all three cases, except when I ran in in GDB where it failed for all three cases - GDB detected the overrun in all three cases.  That is the thing with undefined behaviour - the behaviour is undefined.  What it does demonstrate is the usefulness of using a debugger to debug and test your code.

Comment: @EranAmsellem : In your question, you failed to describe the nature of the "crash", but I suspect the fault was found during OS exit and clean-up which only occurs in `case '0'`.  The error will have corrupted the stack, which can affect adjacent local variables and the return address - in this case the return from `main()` will have failed - i.e. it crashed while exiting, not while processing the `case` block.